# SVN | Add new File Issue only suddenly | Error running context: The server unexpectedly closed the connection

Tags: linux, svn, tortoisesvn

SVN is getting opened on Chrome.

SVN is successfully updating content i.e SVN Update working fine.

For Existing File, it is allowing updates.

When i try to add file, It is giving following issue:
[image]

But it was working fine since yesterday and suddenly stopped working.

I created new directory structure and moved existing directory structure into that. (Many folders and files and moved around 1 gb, and left with some more mb's)

We have access to SVN server in Linux but we are not sure what actually happened. We all are newbies to this (even not sure about installation). Is it server side issue or client side issue? Tried on various systems but no success.

Following link i tried but not able to find 3690 drop not sure how much imp is it:
https://programmerah.com/error-running-context-the-server-unexpectedly-closed-the-connection-24564/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have restarted httpd service and commit worked fine for me.

```
systemctl stop httpd.service
systemctl start httpd.service
```